# Python - big list issue

Tags: python, bigdata

I need to create and search a big list, for example list of 3.9594086612e+65 arrays of 10x10 (or bigger list of bigger arrays).

I need to create list of combinations. After I need to filter out some combinations according to some rule. This process should be repeated till only one combination is left.

If I try to create this list it crashes because of the memory after few minutes.

I can imagine, that solution should be to store the data in different way than list in memory.

What is possible, correct and easy way? SQL database? NoSQL database? Or just multiple text files opened and closed one after one? I need to run through this list multiple times.

Comment: Suggested reading: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You cannot even store that number of *data*.... even if they were one bit each. Either you can avoid memorizing them, which means computing the data on-the-fly when needed, or you have an unsolvable problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy:

`3.9594086612e+65`

It's more than all computer memory in the world.

(And I do not multiply by 10)!

Comment: So, it means that I need generator instead of the list (as only solution)?

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2513110/data-center/scientists-calculate-total-data-stored-to-date--295--exabytes.html), the total data stored in the world is 295 exabytes = 2.95e+20 bytes.

Comment: @matouc: Well, but you can't store a billionth of that list. e+65, imagine! 1Tera octet is 1e12 (one billion byte). So here you have 1e53 Tera… I mean Trillion of trillions of trillions of trillions of trillions (well, quite) :)